# Removing spacing from between table cells

Tags: html, css

(EDIT: Solved. I was on the right track with the border-collapse, but I had to use ctrl+f5 to see it)

Tried using border-collapse and border-spacing to remove them, but it didn't work.

Code:

```
<main>
    <div class="adminr1">
        <section class="adminc1">
            <table class="adminResults">
                <thead>
                    <td>cell</td>
                    <td>cell</td>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>cell</td>
                    <td>cell</td>
                </tr> 
        </table>
    </section>
    </div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
 *
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: small;
        font-family: Roboto;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    main
    {
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 86%;
        min-width: 1000px;
    }
    section
    {
        border: 1px solid #BBB;
        background: #FFF;
        border-radius: 7px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .adminr1
    {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 66%;
        height: 700px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        font-size: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .adminc1
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        font-size: 0;
    }
    /*Table Styles:*/
    .adminResults
    {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .adminResults thead
    {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .adminResults tr td
    {
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

So far, this is the only page I have which uses a table, so I have no table-related styles anywhere else that could be blocking or overwriting the properties I'm trying to add, nor do i have any border-related files on other elements applied generally enough to do the same thing.

I'm obviously missing something, because this seems like it should be a very easy thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`border-collapse`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-collapse/)** property to remove spacing between cells

```
table.adminResults{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/8n6v7/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Nope. Not working. One of the first things I tried. I tried it directly on the element, as well as the class.

Comment: @user3331834 can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I had the tab open and forgot to add it in. Edited.

Comment: Oh hold on. It did work. I had to do a ctrl+f5 to see it. Maybe I did get it right all along, then. Thanks, though. Least I was on the right track.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/8n6v7/1/

Answer (score 0):

add the `border-collapse:collapse;` to table.

```
.adminResults{width:100%;border:1px solid #000;border-collapse: collapse;}
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/n4rsy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Did your try to add `border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` inside table? Like this:

```
<table class="adminResults" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `border-spacing: 0px;` and `border-collapsing: seperate;` on the Table.

```
.adminResults {
   width: 100%;
   border: 1px solid #000;
  border-spacing: 0px;;
  border-collapse: seperate;
 }
```

Check out this updated: [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vNQE9/4/)